# android sdk on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: android-sdk

I'm installing android sdk on ubuntu 13.10 using this guide   http://tutorialforlinux.com/2013/11/25/how-to-install-android-sdk-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy-easy-visual-guide/

I'm stuck on updating android sdk tool and api's step 7. When I `cd /opt/android-sdk*` the command works but when I enter `sudo su -c "tools/android"` command I get bash:

`tools/android: permission denied`

What am I doing wrong and yes I've seen the guide to install open sdk here but I don't want to install the open sdk I need the normal java version.

Comment: IMO the guide is wrong... you don't need root privileges to use the android-sdk

Answer (score -1):

Follow this procedure.

1) Download the Adnroid SDK from the developer site and extract it to your home directory
https://developer.android.com/

2) install java (OPEN) or follow this guide for Oracle Version http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

If you are running a 64-bit distribution of Android SDK on your development machine, you need to install the ia32-libs:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Open up the Android SDK folder in home directory and run Eclipse.

You should be presented wit the Android SDK Gui. You may get couple of window warnings popup the first time you run it, these go away after, so just close them.